# Problems with getting Apple's Remote app working on Windows XP

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have downloaded the [Remote app made by Apple](http://www.apple.com/itunes/remote/), to allow controlling of iTunes via my iPhone.

Following the steps, I am able to

- See my iPhone appear in my iTunes
- Clicking it prompts me to enter my passcode
- Entering the passcode from the iPhone says "verifying remote passcode" in iTunes
- Then it just makes a ding sound and returns me to the blank prompt

I have tried

- Restarting both my computer and iPhone
- Ensuring there are no firewalls running (Comodo and Windows Firewall)

Does anyone know what I might try next to get it to work?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I just updated to the latest iTunes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem a number of times

The thing that works for me is from iTunes: `Edit-> Preferences`.  From the Devices tab, there is a button called 'Forget All Remotes'  give that a click and restart iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

After a **lot** of searching, I found the [answer](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1598264&start=15&tstart=0).

What worked for me was to simply reset my router.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching on this problem the answer was to uninstall Bonjour that came with iTunes and download the latest version and install it. It instantly fixed the problem

Download Bonjour for Windows 1.0.6 here:

http://download.cnet.com/Bonjour-for-Windows/3000-18507_4-93550.html